# CollapsingToolbarLayout Scrolling issues

Tags: toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a problem with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` from the already in Android Studio given `ScrollingActivity`.

The scrolling down motion works perfectly, but when I want to scroll up, it always shows me that the end of the screen is reached without expanding the `Toolbar` again. To expand the `Toolbar`, I have to scroll up again, when the end of the screen is reached.

As I'm not really good in explaining the problem I uploaded a Video on YouTube so you can see it by yourself.

VIDEO: https://youtu.be/WrzsY2ooj9o

Also you can see a little bug in there too. The Toolbar collapses by itself sometimes just by making a "bad motion" with the finger, I think you can see it at 0:11.

Thankful for any Help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.appmac.ron.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It is the same for me, I tried almost everything with no result. I think it is by design and there is no way to tweak this behaviour.

Comment: But there has to be a way, facebook, whatsapp and co. already did that in their apps. @Minas

Comment: Yes, they all use other custom solutions. They did it even before CollapsingToolbarLayout was available. The same with Play Store, it uses something else, you can reverse code to take a look :)

Comment: You can use another library, for example https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar  It has the behaviour you want, the funny thing is I switched from it to use everything from Design library

Comment: @Minas thank you, but i have a generel question. How do I have to handle Desing  Libarys like in your link, when I want to sell my app? Do I need to ask for permission or do I have to buy those? I'am new to this thats why I'm asking.

Comment: the FadingActionBar has Apache license which allows you to do whatever you want with it ( modify, distribute, .. ), take a look to the license, but you should preserve the license text just in case to avoid issues in the future

Answer (score 3):

update to 26.0.0-beta2. AppbarLayout should be work as expect. Details:[Carry on Scrolling](https://chris.banes.me/2017/06/09/carry-on-scrolling/)

<s>Ok, I think a [third party library](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) can make it work. In fact, I decompiled others app and find this:)</s>

All above was deperated, I find this. There is a easy way to solve this problem. Just set a **OnScrollChangeListener** listener to your **nestedsrollview**. The key code is below:

```
nestScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX,
      int oldScrollY) {
    if(scrollY == 0) appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);  
  }
});
```

The animation will do by method appBarLayout itself.

Comment: Unfortunately is not the silver bullet because scroll isn't smooth.

Comment: I've tried every possible solution out there and nothing works for me. I guess this solution suits my needs since it uses snap. This is a bad practice for me but does't matter. The fix isn't even out yet so i have to make do with this. thnx

Comment: @DawidHyży You are right,that wasn't smart way, update to 26.0.0-beta2. AppbarLayout should be work as expect. Details:[Carry on Scrolling](https://chris.banes.me/2017/06/09/carry-on-scrolling/)

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37058076), 
Issue is resolved on ***latest library version 26.1.0***.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37058076) they will re-open to examine.